# Getting data inside from a key from an array of dictionaries in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nsmutabledictionary

I have a dictionary defined as

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *MyDictionary;
```

I tried to get the output like this

```
NSLog(@"%@",MyDictionary);
```

**THIS IS THE OUTPUT I GET**

```
{ Category=(
        {
        code=12; Name="John Smith"
        },
        {
        code=21; Name="Bobby Smith"
        },
        {
        code=31; Name="Smith Jones"
        } );

Detail = {
        code=1;
        Text="Developer"
        };
}
```

My table cells are populated with names, John Smith, Bobby Smith and so on. What I need is to get the code when I click on a particular cell. For eg if I click on name John Smith I should get the value 12

This is my code so far

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *allNames = [MyDictionary allValues];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name == %@", cell.textLabel.text];
    NSArray *filteredNames = [allNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    NSLog(@"%@",filteredNames);

}
```

The filteredNames doesnt contain any filtered objects. How do I get the value of code?

Comment: Is your table grouped by "Category", "Detail" as shown in the MyDictionary output? Or you are only using the "Category" section for the table?

Comment: Only using Category section for the table, I wanted to give an idea on how MyDictionary looks like

Comment: Please show the code where you are setting the value for cell tableView:cellForIndexPath: What about technique you use to set the 'name' should be same technique to get the value 'code'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
   NSString *getCodeValue = [[[myDic objectForKey:@"Category"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"code"]
   NSLog (@"%@", getCodeValue)      
}
```

USe this code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: just as you have provided

Comment: On what basis will this get the codevalue, for eg: if I click the cell with name John Smith how will it know the code should be 12?

Comment: @Gamerlegend - indexPath.row row return `{
        code=12; Name="John Smith"
        },` which is dictionary and has two value 1) 12 which has key name is **code** and 2) "John Smith" which has key name is **Name**, its so simple dude :)

Comment: NSLog (@"%@", getCodeValue)  is still returning (null) also NSLog (@"%@", indexPath.row) returns null value, I'm using xcode 4.2, simulator 5.0 Any advice?

Comment: are you sure you initialize you dic ??

Comment: it worked, it was a case sensitive issue, the 'c' in code is actually capital 'Code'

Answer (score 0):

Assign code to cell's tag and use it in your's didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a subclass of UITableViewCell that simply has a label and an integer value as properties. Then initialise it as below:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellClassNameHere"];
  cell.codeValue = [[myDic objectForKey:@"Category"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Add the following code also in order to retrieve the code when the cell is touched:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSString *codeValue = cell.codeValue;
  NSLog(@"%@", codeValue);
}
```

As mentioned in a comment above, make sure your NSDictionary is being initialised properly:

```
NSMutableDictionary myDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; //This can be replaced with however you're getting your code values.
```

Then you should be good to go! It should be noted that no code posted in this answer is tested, so let me know if you have any issues!

Matt